# Is there an expression to say someone will replace me at a meeting?

Tags: expressions, verbs, expression-choice

I am writing an email to the top management to tell someone will replace
me at a meeting I cannot attend. Is there a good expression / a better
verb for this situation ? Or is 'replace' the good word ? I thought about
"substitute" but it does not sound really better to me.

I want the email to look professional and well written.

Comment: Hello, mguijarr. "Could you possibly find someone to fill in for me?" is perhaps one of the most respectful (and quite formal enough) ways of doing this.

Comment: I already found someone to replace me - I have to say someone will replace me, and tell the name in a nice, formal, respectful way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unfortunately, I am unavailable to attend next week's meeting, so Pat Smith will **stand in** for me.

> **stand in**
>    Deputize.
>
> - *‘I then stood in for another team leader while she was off, and I picked up everything really quickly.’*
> - *‘Ian Bell also pushed his claims by striking an assured 70 when he stood in for Graham Thorpe.’*
>     <sup>Lexico (formerly Oxford Dictionaries)</sup>

synonyms (the most appropriate for the OP's situation, there are others): 
***deputize***, act, substitute, act as substitute, act as stand-in, fill in, sit in,  take over [from me]

Comment: Or *serve as my proxy* or just *represent me*.